# retaining the added clone row

Tags: html, jquery

I need to make table2 length is not going back to the same length of table 1 when adding a row on table 2 and retain its row when reload, for example the table 1 has 3 rows and as the code I give you I want table2 has also have 3 rows but I add another row on table2 then I reloading it the table2 goes back to 3 rows, it should be 4 rows.

I am using sql server to save the data, the data save on it show 4 rows.

```js
var add = 0;
var row = $('#Table_1 tbody tr').length;
const appendRows = () => {
  // get the table 1 rows

  // create an empty string to store the new table 2 rows
  var newRows = '';

  // loop through the table 1 rows

  var itemId = $(this).attr('data-item-id'); // get the unique identifier for this row in table 1

  // create the new row for table 2 and include the unique identifier from table 1

  var newRow = `<tr class="table-row" data-table="">
<td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
<input type="text" name="strCol_01[]" id="strCol01[${add}]" value data-ref="ctrl_item" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted item-action-listener" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" Readonly >
</td>
<td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
<input type="number" name="strCol_02[]" id="strCol02[${add}]" value data-ref="ctrl_quantity" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted item-action-listener" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" Readonly>
</td>
<td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
<input type="number" name="strCol_03[]" id="strCol03[${add}]" value class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext item-action-listener" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
</td>
<td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
<input type="number" name="strCol_04[]" id="strCol04[${add}]" value class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext item-action-listener " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" readonly="" required="">
</td>
<td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
<input type="text" name="strCol_05[]" id="strCol05[${add}]" value class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext item-action-listener" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
</td>
<td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
<input type="datetime-local" name="strCol_06[]" id="strCol06[${add}]" value class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext item-action-listener" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
</td>
</tr>`;

  // append the new row to the string of new table 2 rows
  newRows += newRow;


  // append the string of new table 2 rows to the table 2 body
  $('#table2 tbody').append(newRows);

  // increment the add variable
  add++;
};

for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
  appendRows();
}

$('#Table_1 tbody input').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  const data_column = $this.attr('name');
  const value = $this.val();
  const index = $('#Table_1').find(`input[name="${data_column}"]`).index($this);
  const rows = $('#table2 tbody tr').eq(index);
  $(rows).find(`input[data-ref="${data_column}"]`).val(value);
});

$(document).on('input', '#table2', function() {
  $('#table2 tbody tr').each(function() {
    const rows2 = $(this);
    var Qty = $(rows2).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq"]');
    var Exit = $(rows2).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j"]');
    var Balance = $(rows2).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc"]');
    var Remaining = parseFloat(Qty.val()) - parseFloat(Exit.val());

    if (Exit.val() > Qty.val()) {
      Exit.val(Qty.val())
      Remaining = Qty.val() - Exit.val()
    }

    Balance.val(Remaining)
    Exit.attr('max', Remaining);
  });
});

$(document).on('change', 'input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36"]', function() {
  var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var difval = parentTr.find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc"]').val();

  if (difval > 0) {
    var copy = parentTr.clone().insertAfter(parentTr);
    copy.find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j"],input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9"],input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36"]').val('');
    copy.find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq"]').val(difval);
    parentTr.find('input').prop('disabled', true).css('background', 'lightgreen');

  }
  parentTr.find('input').prop('disabled', true).css('background', 'lightgreen');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered w-100 fs-11 ctrl-table2" id="Table_1">
  <thead class="bg-light">
    <tr>

      <td contenteditable="false">
        <span class="lblColumns" contenteditable="true">Item</span>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="false">
        <span class="lblColumns" contenteditable="true">Quantity</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fal fa-trash-alt text-danger btnDelCol" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="Templates.Table.DelCol(this)" data-original-title="Delete Column"></a>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="false">
        <span class="lblColumns" contenteditable="true">Description</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fal fa-trash-alt text-danger btnDelCol" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="Templates.Table.DelCol(this)" data-original-title="Delete Column"></a>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="false">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fal fa-plus text-success btnAddCol" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="Templates.Table.AddCol(this)" data-original-title="Add Column"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td class="position-relative p-0 " width="100px" data-editable="false">
        <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="ctrl_item" id="Item" value="1" required="" disabled="">
      </td>
      <td class="p-0 " width="100px" "=" " data-editable="false ">
                <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " type="number " name="ctrl_quantity " id="Quantity " value="4 " required=" " disabled=" ">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto; " data-editable="false ">
                <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " type="text " name="ctrl_Description " id="Descrip " value="1 " required=" " disabled=" ">
            </td>
            <td contenteditable="false " width="10px ">
                <a href="javascript:void(0) " class="fal fa-trash-alt text-danger btnDelRow d-none " data-toggle="tooltip " title=" " onclick="Templates.Table.DelRow(this) " data-original-title="Delete Row "></a>
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            
            <td class="position-relative p-0 " width="100px " data-editable="false ">
                <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " type="text " name="ctrl_item " id="Item " value="2 " required=" " disabled=" ">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " width="100px " "="" data-editable="false">
        <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" type="number" name="ctrl_quantity" id="Quantity" value="3" required="" disabled="">
      </td>
      <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;" data-editable="false">
        <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="ctrl_Description" id="Descrip" value="2" required="" disabled="">
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="false" width="10px">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fal fa-trash-alt text-danger btnDelRow d-none" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="Templates.Table.DelRow(this)" data-original-title="Delete Row"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td class="position-relative p-0 " width="100px" data-editable="false">
        <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="ctrl_item" id="Item" value="3" required="" disabled="">
      </td>
      <td class="p-0 " width="100px" "=" " data-editable="false ">
                <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " type="number " name="ctrl_quantity " id="Quantity " value="2 " required=" " disabled=" ">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto; " data-editable="false ">
                <input class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " type="text " name="ctrl_Description " id="Descrip " value="3 " required=" " disabled=" ">
            </td>
            <td contenteditable="false " width="10px ">
                <a href="javascript:void(0) " class="fal fa-trash-alt text-danger btnDelRow d-none " data-toggle="tooltip " title=" " onclick="Templates.Table.DelRow(this) " data-original-title="Delete Row "></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="display: none; ">
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="false " colspan="99 " class="text-right ">
                <a href="javascript:void(0) " class="fal fa-plus text-success btnAddRows " data-toggle="tooltip " title=" " data-original-title="Add Row "></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<form method="post " class="need-validation " novalidate name="formtable " id="formtable " >
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered w-100 fs-11 ctrl-table3 " id="table2 ">
        <thead class="bg-light ">
            <tr>
                <td>Items</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Exit Item Qty</td>
                <td>Balance Qty</td>
                <td>Guard on Duty</td>
                <td>Date and Time</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table_2 "></tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="item-action-listeners " name="btnSubmit " id="btnSubmit "   type="submit "><i class="fa-light fa-pen fa-fw "></i>Save</button>
    <!-- <button class="add-row-btn " name="btnadd "   type="submit " ><i class="fa-light fa-pen fa-fw "></i>add</button> -->
</form>
```

Comment: you should either use a server script to create the initial page, or fetch the data using AJAX and use that to populate the table.

Comment: i already populated the table but the issue is it stay on 3 row but in the database 4 row but if i did this code on the var row = $('Table_1 tbody tr').length + 1; it adds another row

Comment: You should move `var row = ...` inside the `appendRows` function, so it gets the updated value.